# Import pattern for in Typescript with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

This may be Typescript 101 but can't seem to get a clear answer for this.

I am new to Typescript and have come across some existing code (its AngularJS) that follows this format

```
module App.Login {
    import IStateService = angular.ui.IStateService;

    export class LoginController {

        private _state: IStateService;

        constructor($state: angular.ui.IStateService, ...) {
            this._state = $state;
        }
    }
}
```

Through reading around and some experimentation I discovered this can be rewritten in a far leaner manner as the following:

```
module App.Login {  
    export class LoginController {

        constructor(private $state: angular.ui.IStateService, ...) {
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Why was it created the first way originally? Lack of knowledge or for some reason I don't understand
- Why we need to use `import` just to alias the interface
- A question of style, but later in my class to use `$state` I have to use `this.$state`. Coming from Angular v1 this feels odd, I presume this is ok though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why was it originally this way? If you mean the import, convenience. `angular.ui.IStateService` is right on the edge of annoyingly long. They author probably just wanted a more convenient version. If you mean the declaration of the private var, some folks (especially coming from a C#/Java background) would prefer to declare class parameters explicitly. The visibility modifier (`public`/`protected`/`private`) on constructor parameters syntax is pretty unique to typescript so folks aren't used to it / don't like it.
2. You don't. You can use the `type` keyword instead.
3. Yep, that's totally fine.